# Symlinks are not working in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

After updating my extensions and also the symlink link in the di.xml file
My site has lost its appearance, the slides, products, buttons and all the links do not work.

Frontend: http://prntscr.com/wfvfl9

Backend: http://prntscr.com/wfvenp

http://prntscr.com/wfwg1b

Comment: what is your store and admin user lenguage ??

Comment: My store frontend and admin is in French langage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Run the below Commands,**

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f en_US fr_FR
php bin/magento c:f
```

Comment: Thank you Madani everything works very well ....